# Какой смысл в макрофункциях без replacement-list?

Tags: c++, qt, macro

Я фактически никогда не сталкивался с ситуацией, когда мне приходилось бы ипользовать макрофункции. Но из любопытства, перейдя к определению `Q_INVOKABLE`, увидел вот что:

```
#define Q_INVOKABLE  QT_ANNOTATE_FUNCTION(qt_invokable)
```

и дальше:

```
#ifndef QT_ANNOTATE_FUNCTION
# define QT_ANNOTATE_FUNCTION(x)
#endif
```

На [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) написано, что *replacement-list* является *optional*, да я и сам знаю, что, по крайней мере для *object-like*, просто будет определяться пустой макрос. **Но какой в этом толк от макрофункции? Что должно дать определение?**

```
QT_ANNOTATE_FUNCTION(qt_invokable)
```

Comment: Ну видимо макрос не всегда пустой (`#ifndef` все-таки).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это прото защита от повторного включения же. У него просто нет замены, так зачем он нужен в принципе? Я бы мог предположить что метку `qt_invokable` как-то MOC распарсит, но тогда зачем макрофункция и что на ёё место встанет...

Comment: Вряд ли защита от повторного включения (во-первых их обычно вешают на целые хедеры, а во вторых для макросов повторное определение - не ошибка). Скорее нужно чтобы можно было при желании определить макрос из другого места, например через флаги компилятора или еще что-то.

Comment: Конкретный и полезный вопрос. Плюс от меня.  Я не стану отвечать(затрудняюсь сочинять ответ), но, в принципе: чтобы иметь функцию на  на этапе препроцессинга,(работать с любым (мета) объектом)

Answer (score 3):

`Q_INVOKABLE`, как и многие другие макросы [языковых расширений QT](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html), предназначен для обработки QT Meta-Object Compiler, который осуществляет кодогенерицию.

см https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, есть какая-то отладочная функция.

```
#define DEBUG_LOG(x)  какой-то вывод в журнал
```

А потом в release-программе просто объявляется

```
#define DEBUG_LOG(x)
```

и все, вывод просто отключен.

Comment: Но `Q_INVOKABLE`, наоборот, должен пометить метод для MOC для проброса в QML.

Comment: Ну еще один макрос, который разворачивается в макрос, который... Вас же интересовал не конкретно `Q_INVOKABLE`, а "*Какой смысл в макрофункциях без replacement-list?*"

Comment: ... который разворачиватеся в ничто. В этом то и беда. Непонятно как он должен работать, если ничего на своё место не подставит.

Comment: Никак! В том и логика, что — убрать его совсем, если не нужен.